# Cannot run function on geometry column: PostGIS identifies geometry column as type varchar

Tags: postgis

I am getting a weird error. I am trying to run `ST_Contains()` and a table.

```
UPDATE 
    public.foo
SET 
    ...
FROM 
    public.bar
WHERE 
    ST_Contains(bar.geometry, foo.geom);
```

However, when I run this, I am getting

> function public.st_contains(character varying, public.geometry) does not exist
> LINE 6:     WHERE public.ST_Contains(bar.geometry, foo.geom) A...
> ^
> HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

First I thought something is wrong with my PostGIS installation and/or the namespace... But I can run PostGIS functions in this database. On other tables as well as in other schemas.
So I investigated table `bar` and its `geometry` column, beause apparently `ST_Contains()` thinks its of `character varying`. And it was of type `var char`. So I converted it to `geometry` using

```
ALTER TABLE 
    public.bar 
ALTER COLUMN 
    geometry 
TYPE 
    geometry(Multipolygon, 4326) 
USING 
    st_AsText(geometry);
```

Now its of type `geometry`. Now it also appears in the `geometry_column` View (which it did not before):

However, when I now run the `ST_Contains`, it still returns the same error... So I assume there is still something wring with the `geometry` column?

Comment: Can you do any geometry operation like `ST_IsValid` or `ST_GeometryType` on `public.bar.geometry`. And as a shot in the dark, can you rename column `geometry` to something like `geom` to maybe avoid a reserved word.

Comment: @FranciscoPuga yes I can. I think I am getting to the bottom of it. When I do a `SELECT column_name, data_type FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = 'bar';` I see that `geometry` column is of `type` `USER-DEFINED` which I think is odd. I typecasted `geometry` column the following `ALTER TABLE  public.bar ALTER COLUMN geometry TYPE geometry(Multipolygon, 4326) USING ST_AsText(geometry);` It gave no errors, but still this type `USER-DEFINED`.

Comment: @FranciscoPuga I tried to duplicate the column `geometry` by adding another column `geom` via `SELECT public.AddGeometryColumn ('public','bar','geom',4326,'MULTIPOLYGON', 2);` and then `UPDATE public.bar SET geom = geometry;` but when I check `SELECT column_name, data_type FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = 'country';` `geom` is of `type`USER-DEF`

Comment: `USER-DEFINED` in `information.schema.columns.data_type` is fine, as `geometry` is a kind of user defined type, not postgresql native but defined by postgis extension. I have the same in my dbs. Still having problems with the new `geom` column

Comment: Please read your statement carefully: you are altering the column type `USING ST_AsText(<varchar_column>)` - creating **a text representation of a text representation**. PG is given the ability to auto-cast WKT to `GEOMETRY` types, but it seems you have defeated its capabilities here...